# Bootstrap access dropdown menuitem elements (name, href, text)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdown menu nested in order like this:

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sensors</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#1">Sensor 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#2">Sensor 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#3">Sensor 3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#4">Sensor 4</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#5">Sensor 5</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<p id="sensor_cur" class="small">Sensor 000</p>
```

I tried to access elements like this:

```
$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var href = $('a.dropdown-item').attr('href');
 var element=document.getElementById("sensor_cur"); 
 element.innerHTML = href;
});
```

The issue is that I always getting **#1** from **href** value no matter what menu-item I will click on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all the `.dropdown-item` elements within the event handler. To access the `href` of the one which is clicked use the `this` keyword instead.

Also note that you can make the code more succinct by using jQuery to update the text in the `#sensor_cur` element. Try this:

```js
$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $("#sensor_cur").text(href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sensors</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#1">Sensor 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#2">Sensor 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#3">Sensor 3</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#4">Sensor 4</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#5">Sensor 5</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p id="sensor_cur" class="small">Sensor 000</p>
```